# What will be the query for displaying isbn, title, Author's (all the book authors in single line) from the given tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Book_title Table 
+---------------+-------------------+
| isbn          | title             |
+---------------+-------------------+
| 9780195153446 | classical         |
| 9780374157067 | flu: the stor     |
+---------------+-------------------+

Book_Authors table
+---------------+--------------------+
| Isbn_id       | Author             |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 9780195153446 | mark p. o. morford |
| 9780195153446 | robert j. lenardon |
| 9780374157067 | gina kolata        |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

What will be the query for displaying 
isbn, title, Author's (all the book authors in single line) from the given tables.
Each book might have multiple authors.

sample output:

```
isbn                  title               author                author
9780195153446        classical      mark p. o. morford     robert j. lenardon
9780374157067        flu: the stor     gina kolata
```

I used this query

```
Select isbn, title, author from Book_title, Book_author Where Book_title.isbn = Book_author.isbn_id
```

but this gives me two results for the same book if it has two authors

Comment: In php, loop over all results and for each row add authors in an array ?

Comment: Ayrton's solution is the one I'd go with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group_concat  (and use explit JOIN instead of old where based relation)

```
      Select a.isbn, a.title, group_concat(b.author )
      from Book_title, 
      INNER JOIN Book_authoron a.isbn = b.isbn_id
      group by a.isbn, a.title
```